# column datatypes in postgres trigger

Tags: postgresql

Background: I am using logical decoding (wal2json) to get updates from a db and it works wonderfully except for the fact that view traffic does not come through logical decoding because its not represented in the WAL.

My idea to get around this is to put a trigger on a view which then sends the row change as json on a channel via `pg_notify()`. Getting the row as json was easy: `to_jsonb(NEW)` but where I am stuck is getting the column data types along with it. Wal2json presents row changes as such:

```
{
        "kind": "insert",
        "schema": "public",
        "table": "table1_with_pk",
        "columnnames": ["a", "b", "c"],
        "columntypes": ["integer", "character varying(30)", "timestamp without time zone"],
        "columnvalues": [2, "Tuning", "2018-03-27 11:58:28.988414"]
}
```

I would like to get my channel notify solution to have  similar output, is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand: if you `UPDATE` a view, the changes to the underlying tables will be WAL logged and decoded. What exactly is missing?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*view traffic*"?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.cn/docs/13/logical-replication-restrictions.html

"Replication is only supported by tables, including partitioned tables. Attempts to replicate other types of relations, such as views, materialized views, or foreign tables, will result in an error."